# VBA application.match does not find all values in lookup range

Tags: vba, excel

I've looked around but no posts about a peculiar problem I am having. I am trying to find a combination of GGID (id) and country in a row. In my sheet, there are 4 rows with a given GGID but with different countries, then over 1000 rows with other ggids and then the correct GGID and correct country.

The function looks like this:

```
Function rangefinder2(ByVal ggid As Long, ByRef sheet As Worksheet, ByVal country) As Object

Dim wbMain As Workbook
Set wbMain = ThisWorkbook
Dim loopback As Long
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer, z As Long
Dim adresik As Long
loopback = 1

    For x = 1 To 15
        If sheet.Cells(1, x) = "Pays" Then Exit For
    Next x
    For y = 1 To 15
        If sheet.Cells(1, y) = "GGID" Then Exit For
    Next y

    z = sheet.range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    sheet.Activate      'AST: if you remove this, next line throws an error

    Do

        If Not IsError(Application.Match(CLng(ggid), _
                       sheet.range(Cells(loopback, y), Cells(z, y)), 0)) Then

            adresik = Application.Match(ggid, _
                      sheet.range(Cells(loopback, y), Cells(z, y)), 0)

            If Cells(adresik + loopback, x) = country Then
                Set rangefinder2 = Cells(adresik + loopback, y)
                Exit Function
            End If
        Else
            Set rangefinder2 = Nothing
            Exit Function
        End If

        If loopback = 1 Then
            loopback = adresik
        Else
            loopback = loopback + adresik
        End If
    Loop

End Function
```

Comment: the sheet is passed correctly (I checked with sheet.name), values x, y and z are calculated correctly.  The match finds first four rows (67 -71) but then fails to find the last one (1600). Value z(representing end of range) is 1601. I don't get it :/ Your help will be appreciated.

So I made a test array to illustrate this easier:

GGID    |s Pays 
499455  |s Djibouti 
499455  |s Italie
13  |s Pologne
499455  |s Afrique du Sud
499455  |s Afrique du Sud

Comment: Perhaps you have a blank row somewhere. In any case I would use the Find method or AutoFilter.

Comment: No blank rows, the CurrentRegion.Rows.Count (z) is 1601, which is the last line. The searched for result is in row 1600 (and 1601 as well). 

Find is way to slow, autofilter cannot be used because the order of the rows cannot be changed.

Comment: Find isn't slow and I don't follow your objection to AF. Step through your code and check the value of variables and you will no doubt find one which is not as you expect.

Comment: Tim Williams - no, because loopback goes up only when the next result is found. This is not the problem anyway.

Comment: @SJR: there are tests of match vs find vs variant array, find is the slowest.  https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/

As for the autofilter, it would require a massive overhead to change the solution I have now. Anyway, can anyone tell me WHY that last value is not found?

Comment: May be for many reasons... blancs, case sensitiveness, etc. `If Cells(adresik + loopback, x) = country` ... Try `If LCase(Trim(Cells(adresik + loopback, x))) = LCase(Trim(country))` ?

Comment: Hey ASH, thanks for comment. 
The code fails at the application.match, meaning it doesn't even find the GGID.

Please note that the GGID is a long variable, so no spaces or casing is taken into account. Just to make sure, I do convert the ggid into long 

If Not IsError(Application.Match(CLng(ggid), ...

Comment: what are the values of `loopback`, `z` and `y` when `If Not IsError(Application.Match(CLng(ggid), sheet.range(Cells(loopback, y), Cells(z, y)), 0))` returns the unexpected error?

Comment: So I made a test array to illustrate this easier:

row1: GGID Pays 
row2:499455 Djibouti
row3:499455 Italie
row4:13 Pologne
row5:499455 Afrique du Sud
row6:499455 Afrique du Sud

Comment: I'm not sure that converting to long solves the problem. For instance, comparing numbers with an `exact match` (parameter 0)... the cell has a number formatted as double. I have a feeling that it may have to do with some `epsilon` difference.

Comment: A.S.H. you were right. It was the format of the cell in the range. Man application.match SUCKS! Thank you for your patience!

Comment: `.AutoFilter` doesn't change the order. Maybe you can look into Power Query/Microsoft Query or ADODB to query the data

Comment: @AdamEs I am not sure it's only `Match`.. Any other method such as VLookup should've faced the same issue, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

```
'Find the cells having formulas in sheet and add it to dictionaries
Function FindAllInSheet() As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim sFormulaKey As String
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim formulaDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim fRange As Range, strFirstAdd As String


    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    sFormulaKey = "=TEST"
    Set formulaDict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    'find the project name
    Set fRange = wks.Cells.Find(what:=sFormulaKey, SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookAt:=xlPart)

    If Not fRange Is Nothing Then

        'get the address of the first occurence
        strFirstAdd = fRange.Address
        If Not formulaDict.Exists(fRange.Address) Then
            formulaDict.Add fRange.Address, fRange.Formula
        End If

        'loop till  project name range is not found or first address is reached
        Do
            Set fRange = wks.Cells.Find(what:=sFormulaKey, After:=fRange, SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookAt:=xlPart)

            If fRange Is Nothing Then
                Exit Do
            End If

            If fRange.Address = strFirstAdd Then
                Exit Do
            End If

            If Not formulaDict.Exists(fRange.Address) Then
                formulaDict.Add fRange.Address, fRange.Formula
            End If

        Loop While Not fRange Is Nothing

        'Return the Dictionary
        Set FindAllInSheet = formulaDict

    End If

End Function


'Find the cell having formulas in selected range and add it to dictionaries
Function FindAllInSelection() As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim sFormulaKey As String
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim formulaDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim fRange As Range, strFirstAdd As String


    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    sFormulaKey = "=TEST"
    Set formulaDict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    For Each fRange In Selection
        If InStr(LCase(fRange.Formula), LCase(sFormulaKey)) > 0 Then
            If Not formulaDict.Exists(fRange.Address) Then
                formulaDict.Add fRange.Address, fRange.Formula
            End If
        End If
    Next fRange

    'Return the Dictionary
    Set FindAllInSelection = formulaDict



End Function
```

Comment: Just giving some code is not a good answer, its better to explain what you are doing or point out if there were any mistakes in OP's approach